# Why does ls -a not show files that finder does show?

Tags: terminal, finder, bash

When navigating to `/usr/local/bin` a file called "R" can be seen:

[image]

But when `cd /usr/local/bin` and `ls` (or `ls -a`), we see a long list of files, but no file called R:

[image]

I was surprised by this - apparently finder can see files that `ls` cannot. Why doesn't `ls -a` show all files that finder does?

Comment: Is that the whole list?  It's important to note that sorting in Finder is different than the sorting in Bash/Zsh.  Issue the command `ls -ad R*` and let me know what you get.

Comment: @Allan ah. I get `R  Redirect Rscript`.

Comment: I'll write up an answer....

Comment: Wouldn't `ls -1 | sort -f` give you the same results  as the finder?

Comment: @fd0 You're right. I'll use `ls -1 | sort -f` in future rather than `ls`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's there, but you're not seeing it because it's not where you're expecting it to be because the sorting in Finder is different than the sorting in Bash/Zsh.  Basically Finder does a case insensitive search whereas Bash is case sensitive.  For example, "a" follows "Z"

If you're looking for a specific file and you know the case, you can use a little `ls` magic to find it...

```
$ ls -Ad R*
```

Where...

- `-A` = List all files, except `.` and `..`
- `-d` = Treat directories as files and do not search them recursively
- `R*` = All files that begin with the letter "R"

Comment: Not saying this is wrong, as the upvotes and acceptance show that, but I just don't understand. Surely if it's just a case of sorting the list differently, then in bash you'd expect to see the file at the top of the list. But it looks to me like it's not there at all?

Comment: I think the OP has just shown part of the output.

Comment: @TomBowen In the OP, I cropped the list to show only a few files, as there were [`ls -1 | wc -l`](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x700.html) = 1047 files in total. Interesting, only 26 of them started with either a number or an upper case letter (which is why I missed some of those files, including "R").

Comment: _"Basically Finder does a case insensitive search whereas Bash is case sensitive."_ - This has nothing to do with bash though; it's ls which decides to sort its output that way (likely in response to locale settings), the shell is irrelevant in this behaviour.

Comment: @marcelm Yes, ls uses LC_COLLATE to determine the collation, usually using something like readdir/scandir + setlocale at program startup.